# coefficient of operator for $B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, generating-functions

We start with the following:
$$
(x+z)^2 - x^2 = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x^2]
$$

$$
(x+z)^2 - x^2 = z(2x+z)
$$

$$
z^k(2x+z)^k = \sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n
$$

Where
$$
Y^{\Delta}(x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)
$$
Therefore:
$$
(2x)^k [z^{n-k}]\left(1+\frac{z}{2x}\right)^k
$$

$$
= (2x)^k [z^{n-k}] \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} \left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)^k
$$

$$
= (2x)^{2k-n} {n-1 \choose n-k}
$$
Is this correct? I feel like this is very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last calculation is somewhat wrong (see *Hints* below). Everything else is ok.

> Let's start from 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left[(x+z)^2-x^2\right]^k=z^k(2x+z)^k = \sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   Then we know from *[this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5065v1.pdf)* by V. Kruchinin, that
>   \begin{align*}
> Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)
> \end{align*}

(*Hint:* $Y^{\Delta}$ has three arguments)

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)&=[z^n]\sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n\\
> &=[z^n]z^k(2x+z)^k\\
> &=(2x)^k[z^{n-k}]\left(1+\frac{z}{2x}\right)^k\\
> &=(2x)^k[z^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=(2x)^k\binom{k}{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right)^{n-k}\\
> &=(2x)^{2k-n}\binom{k}{n-k}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

(*Hint:* The exponent of $\frac{z}{2x}$ in (2) is $j$, not $k$)

We conclude from (3)

> The Bellpolynomials $B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)$ are 
>   \begin{align*}
> B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)=\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}(2x)^{2k-n}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We can generalise the problem from $x^2$ to $x^N$ with $N>0$ a positive integer. A nice by-product is, when specializing the result to $N=2$ we will derive a binomial identity.

> **Generalisation:**
>
> We consider the $k$-th power of $Y(x+z)=(x+z)^N-x^N$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [Y(x,z)]^k&=[(x+z)^N-x^N]^k\\
> &=x^{Nk}\left[\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^N-1\right]^k\\
> &=x^{Nk}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^{Nj}(-1)^{k-j}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Similarly to (1) we observe
>   \begin{align*}
> [(x+z)^N-x^N]^k=x^{Nk}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^{Nj}(-1)^{k-j}=\sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n
> \end{align*}

Again, we know from *[this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5065v1.pdf)* by V. Kruchinin, that
\begin{align*}
Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^N}(x)
\end{align*}

It follows
\begin{align*}
\frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^N}(x)&=[z^n]\sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n\\
&=[z^n]x^{Nk}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^{Nj}(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=x^{Nk}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}[z^n]\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^{Nj}(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=x^{Nk}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{Nj}{n}x^{-n}(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=x^{Nk-n}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{Nj}{n}(-1)^{k-j}
\end{align*}

> We conclude, the Bellpolynomials $B_{n,k}^{x^N}(x)$ are 
>   $$B_{n,k}^{x^N}(x)=x^{Nk-n}\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{Nj}{n}(-1)^{k-j}$$
>
> The special case $N=2$ results in
>   $$B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)=x^{2k-n}\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{2j}{n}(-1)^{k-j}$$

Comparing this result with (4) above we observe

> the following binomial identity is valid for $n\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{2j}{n}(-1)^{k-j}=2^{2k-n}\binom{k}{2k-n}\qquad\quad 1\leq k \leq n
> \end{align*}

Comment: I actually have found the same result I just forgot to update the question haha, but now I have a better understanding of what is going on here! I have found an interesting identity that I wish to try to analyse myself for a bit. If it gets out of hand for me or i just hit a point where I cannot do anything i will be sure to send it to you. Best of luck with the proof :)

Comment: @EricLawson: Good to hear, that you found the mistakes by yourself. Did you also recognize the binomial identity?  Don't forget to upvote, accept helpful answers, otherwise you hardly receive further answers from those guys.